# How Cucumber do to instantiate an object from the feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a class `UnregisteredUser` which generate a random email on its constructor.

```
public UnregisteredUser() {
    this.email = "auto"
            + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10)
            + "@mail.com";
}
```

On the other hand on my feature file I have an step like

```
When the user fills mandatory fields on registration form
  | name | surname | email            |
  | Mr   | Bean    | nonExistentEmail |
```

And the step implementation

```
@When("^the user fills mandatory fields on registration form$")
public void the_user_fills_mandatory_fields_on_registration_form(List<UnregisteredUser> information) {
    UnregisteredUser unregisteredUser = information.get(0);
    UnregisteredUser unregisteredUser1 = new UnregisteredUser();
}
```

I am trying to understand how cucumber works in this last method. When the object is included in the list `information` the object constructor is not being considered. But (for sure) is being considered on `new UnregisteredUser()`

Comment: Which version are u using?

Comment: For cucumber-java i am working with 2,4,0 version.

Comment: XStream is used for creating objects. This was changed from version 3 onwards. Check out cucumber.runtime.table.TableConverter -> https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v2.4.0/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/table/TableConverter.java. Look at the convert() method.